# Check that $M{_m}{_n}(\Bbb F)$ is a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Check that $M{_m}{_n}(\Bbb F)$ is a vector space.

The previous problem I solved was to check that $M{_m}{_n}(\Bbb R)$ is a vector space so I'm wondering what's the difference between those 2 problems?

Comment: You have a general field $\mathbb{F}$ in this case. But everything should more or less be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to show

1) $M_1+M_2\in M_{mn}(\mathbb{F})$ for all $M_1,M_2\in M_{mn}(\mathbb{F})$.

2) $\alpha M\in V$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$ and $M\in M_{mn}(\mathbb{F})$.